How does MPGVAE calculate its reconstruction loss?
I recently came across the Graph Deconvolutional Generation paper where the author propose MPGVAE as a generative model for graphs. They present it as sort of an improvement of GraphVAE, with one major benefit being the fact that they do not require expensive (approximate) graph matching during training to match out- and input graphs for calculation of the reconstruction loss.
I was wondering what their alternative way of determining a loss is, though. If I understood the concept correctly, they encode the input graph to a single, graph-level latent representation and, from thereon, decode into individual node- and edge feature vectors again afterwards. However, how could you make sure that the ordering of the output nodes matches the input, so that both graphs $G$ and $\tilde{G}$ can be compared properly?
